# R Forecast Function Error Out in OBIEE12c

Tags: r

We I run the forecast package in obiee12c, encountered the following error message.

```
[nQSError: 43119] Query Failed: Error(s): Error in library(OBIEEAdvancedAnalytics): there is no package called ‘OBIEEAdvancedAnalytics’ (HY000)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Rcurl might not installed in your system. The following workaround might help you to fix the issue.

First, install curl-devel

Then, execute ./RInstaller.sh installpackages" command

Visit the document (Doc ID 2229530.1) for more detail to fix the issue.